# Как следует переводить фразу "code block"?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, markdown, блок-кода

На странице [Справка по Markdown -> Форматирование комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) упоминается сокращение для ссылки "*code block*".

С переводом, казалось бы, всё просто - "*блок кода*". Но проблема в том, что его (сокращения) описание выглядит так:

> link to the markdown editing help page. Link text is "**code block**".

То есть текст ссылки на *страницу справки по редактированию markdown* будет - "*блок кода*"!?

Я посмотрел - ни на всех переведённых аналогах SO (испанский, португальский и японский), ни на сайте "Русский язык" эта фраза не переведена.

Comment: [code block]...<- здесь будет "блок кода" по-русски

Answer (score 2):

Сделать "блок кода" и согласовать с перводом в справке. Должно быть нормально. Пример как оно выглядит в итоге сейчас можно увидеть в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12783/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-code-block#comment55614_12783) под вопросом.